# How to fix "Unexpectedly found nil" in app Delegate when setting UITabBarController as root view controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zh2Cb.png)As per the screenshots, I was trying to set a UITabBarController as my root view controller. In the storyboard, a UITabBarController is my initial VC, however I get this issue.

I check the storyboard if the tab bar controller is my initial view controller, and if I messed up with unwrapping anything.

```
        let tabController = window!.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
        if let tabViewControllers = tabController.viewControllers {
            let navController = tabViewControllers[0] as! UINavigationController
            let controller = navController.viewControllers.first as! CurrentLocationViewController
            controller.managedObjectContext = managedObjectContext
        }
        return true
    }
```

expected: To run smoothly
actually result: the app launches, crashes on the launch. and I get the following error:
THREAD ONE FATAL ERROR: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping optional.

Comment: you do force unwrap at many places . Its hard to tell, where the issue is. Please post at which line the app crashes.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri The app crashes on line: let tabController = window!.rootViewController as! UITabBarController

Comment: your rootController is not a tabController then...

Comment: could be because window is nil. Show code where you have set the value to window  parameter ?

Comment: im still learning so I may be wrong, but I started as a single view app, then added then embedded my controllers in a tab bar controller via storyboard, would that be setting it as the root? or am I missing something?

Comment: Use the debugger. Check if `window` is nil. If not, see what its `rootViewController` really is.

Comment: Window is nil. How would I fix that issue

Comment: you may not assigned anything to the window variable. If you want to access the window , you can do it by UIApplication.shared.window and assign this to the window variable.

Comment: Embarrasing, but it was because of Xcode beta. the code should have been in the SceneDelegate instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That line is crashing because either window is nil or the view controller is not a UITabBarController. If you remove the code inside didFinishLaunchingWithOptions does your app load without crashing and display the view controller you are expecting?

If so, maybe try moving the code to set the managed object context inside CurrentLocationViewController's viewDidLoad method:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
```

If the app still crashes or does not display the tabbed view controller you are expecting, you might not have the initial view controller set up correctly.

Comment: The OP commented that `window` is `nil`.

Answer (score -1):

Its an ugly way of doing it though... 
to be super safe do this:

```
guard let tabController = window!.rootViewController as? UITabBarController else { return }
let viewControllers = tabControllers.viewControllers
if let navController = viewControllers.first as? UINavigationController { 
   if let controller = navController.viewControllers.first as? CurrentLocationViewController {
        controller.managedObjectContext = managedObjectContext
   }
}
```

Comment: This just prevents the crashes. It doesn't actually fix the problem.